# Hey, watch your step!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

One day, while hiking in the Jungles, we discovered a place hidden inside the woods. It seemed like it was sitting there quietly for some years now. We approached the gate. A friend of mine knocked on the door. There came a voice -

*"You need a password to enter. Watch your step!"*

That's it. Nothing else. Every time we knocked the door, the same voice said the same thing again and again. Finally, we decided to crack this code.

I will keep the mystery for you to solve. We are already in. Do join us by cracking the pass code. Oh, here's the door.

[image]

And, here's what the transcribed note says -

```
   A               B             C              D             E           F
(1,2-2,1)      (4,1-4,2)     (5,1-5,2)     (5,1-5,2)      (5,1-1,1)   (5,1-1,1)
(1,2–2,2)      (4,2-5,3)     (5,2-5,3)     (5,2-5,3)      (5,2-1,2)   (5,2-1,2)
               (5,3-1,3)     (5,2-1,2)     (5,2-1,2)      (5,3-1,3)   (5,1-5,2)
               (1,3-1,2)     (1,2-1,1)     (1,2-1,1)      (5,1-5,2)   (5,2-5,3)
               (1,2-5,1)     (1,1-5,1)     (1,1-5,1)      (5,2-5,3)   (5,2-1,3)
               (5,1-4,1)                                              (1,1-1,2)
```

You won't need any confirmation for the pass code. But, in case if you do -

> Xwrisikcjh! $\leftarrow$ Apply the pass code as key!

<sub><sup>(Note-Story is just for flavor!)</sup></sub>

Comment: There's no note mentioned in the flavor text!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The password is

> **COPPER**

We find this by realizing that

> each set is a list of points to connect.  Each "tile" has 5 columns of dots, numbered left to right as 1,2,3,4,5.  Each column has a number of dots in it, either 1, 2, or 3, numbered from top to bottom.

Then ....

> Connect the dots as listed, according to the numeric layout I described, but realize that each set of connections starts with the left-most side of the figure to be drawn — that is, 5-1,1-1 starts with the 5th column of a tile, and proceeds ***left to right*** so extends to the 1st column of the *adjacent tile*.  Following the instructions thus given yields this:
>  [image]
>   Or, COPPER.

Using this as a Vigenere key,

> Xwrisikcjh! -> victorious!

<sub>(Thanks to @Techidiot for a helpful hint in TSL, and to @MOehm whose comment confirmed what I gleaned from the hint by having already figured that out.)</sub>

Comment: I think that the dots wrap and that 5 refers to the 5th column of the previous brick. Then you'll get [slightly nicer letters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ijHK.png).

Comment: Ahh.  That was my next guess.

Comment: Here goes the tick! :)